# Error: Install-Package Authenticode issuer in PowerShell module

Tags: powershell, tfs, powershell-5.0

We've set up a TFS package repository for hosting internally developed PS 5.1 modules. Before publishing, we sign these POSH modules using the GoDaddy code signing certificate. All was working fine until this morning when we start getting below mentioned error on

```
Install-Module -Name DeploymentHelpers -RequiredVersion 0.2.0 -Repository 'CI' -Force
```

I'm positive that nothing has been changed from the application development side or the cert.

This is the error we are getting:

> PackageManagement\Install-Package : Authenticode issuer
>   'System.Object[]' of the new module
>   'DeploymentHelpers' with version '0.2.0' is not
>   matching with the authenticode issuer  'System.Object[]' of the
>   previously-installed module 'DeploymentHelpers' with
>   version '0.2.0'. If you still want to install or update, use
>   -SkipPublisherCheck parameter. At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1772
>   char:21
>   + ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
>   +                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package],
>   Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AuthenticodeIssuerMismatch,Validate-ModuleAuthenticodeSignature,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

I'm on Windows 2012 R2 and TFS 2017.1

Also, here is the CI repo details:

```
Register-PSRepository `
    -Name CI `
    -SourceLocation "http://tfs:8080/tfs/Projects/_packaging/CI/nuget/v2" `
    -PublishLocation 'http://tfs:8080/tfs/Projects/_packaging/CI/nuget/v2' `
    -PackageManagementProvider Nuget `
    -InstallationPolicy Trusted
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I already tried the suggested answer in SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53269012/error-install-package-authenticode-issuer-system-object-when-running-upd) , but no luck.

Comment: Hi, what about the solutions the below provided? Does it can help you solve the issue? If the solution works for you , you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)  which can let other SO users know whether the solution is works. If the error still occur, feel free to leave comment:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Authenticode issuer 'System.Object[]' of the new module
>   'DeploymentHelpers' with version '0.2.0' is not matching with the
>   authenticode issuer 'System.Object[]' of the previously-installed
>   module 'DeploymentHelpers' with version '0.2.0'.

This is a known issue which exists in `PowerShellGet v1.0.0.1`. You can follow the file path to check the source validate script:`C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1`.

Firstly, please focus on the function `Get-AuthenticodePublisher`. This is the first function which used to get and validate the `SignerCertificate` of the module. You can analyze its script. Express this logic in one sentence is **it walks up the certificate chain**. This means, now, you have been treated as the **"same"** publisher by `PowerShellGet` because the signing certificate you provided same with the one in the chain of the cert which is being checked.

Now, there has 3 solution can for you refer to.

- The first one is add the parameter which shown in the error message:
  `-SkipPublisherCheck`. With this parameter, it can proactively
  **ignore** the certificate verification step. Thus, the error will disappear.
- The second solution is modify the file `PSModule.psm1` by adding the
  script `Select-Object -First 1` into the function
  `Get-AuthenticodePublisher`. As I mentioned previously, the treat
  caused by the same certificates. Now, use `Select-Object` can just
  pick up the first one.
- The last solution is, you'd better upgrade the `PowerShellGet` version to the [latest](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet) since this
  logic issue has been fixed from `PowerShellGet v2.1.4`: [Module publisher verification](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/commit/8cf4052cf8feb3653102626179c9d2b3ee70d442).

Note: if you choose the third one, you need pay attention to the [requirements](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet#requirements) for the latest `PowerShellGet` version:

[image]

Comment: So, if I go with the third option, do I need to meet both the requirements? As I have PowerShell 5.1 already installed on agent. So do I need to install PowerShell Core too?

Comment: @Sam. Yes, these two requirement need to be met at the same time.

Comment: Ah ok! I have to revert to the first option then as I can't install POSH Core at this time. Thanks!

Comment: I got some time and made it work without any issues. Here is what I did:

`Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force`

`Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force`

`Update-Module -Name PowerShellGet`

The version of PowerShell installed is 5.1 on my box. 

With this, I don't need to **SkipPublisherCheck**

Thanks!

Comment: I am in trouble with `Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnector.PowerShell` even after updating `PowerShellGet`... so I had to use `-SkipPublisherCheck`